# How to keep icons aligned strictly inside div?

Tags: html, css

I am making a sidebar and am new to css. I created a div which represents a closed sidebar. It is supposed to only show the icons. Unfortunately the icons come in a misaligned manner inside the div based on their size. How do I fix this?

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 492px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #db3d44;
}

.data-icon {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 9px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hamburger {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  color: black;
}

.sidenav-closed {
  width: 65px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="sidenav-closed sidenav">
  <button class="hamburger data-disappear">&#9776;</button>
  <div class="icons-only">
    <div class="data-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="data-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="data-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The car icon is misaligned here. What's the solution?

Comment: I found that latest (5.5) version of FA has narrower car icon. https://fontawesome.com/icons/car?style=solid

Comment: Your `.data.icon` use `float: left` and with that won't center as they collapse to their content and then _float to the left_. Give them `text-align: center` and then either set their width to 100% or remove float (which I recommend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to align all the icons to the center so your .data-icon class could look like this:

```
.data-icon {
    font-size: 45px;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` elements doesn't have set `width` and `height` in CSS - so the icons are strictly aligned inside them.

If you want to vertically center them and learn something new use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
.icons-only { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

and

```
.data-icon {
   ...
   margin-left:0
}
```

Your car icon is also a little bit bigger than house - you can a little change it size by add new class to it or use this:

```
.data-icon:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

This CSS code will take second (=2) element with class `.data-icon` and set different font size for it

Answer (score 0):

The icons are inline elements so they will be left aligned by default. Add in that the icons are not that same size (this is normal), you get an uneven alignment.

To remedy this, add `text-align: center` to `.icons-only`.

Note: Given the layout in the example, it does not appear necessary to float `.data-icon` to the left.

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 492px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #db3d44;
}

.icons-only { 
  text-align: center;
}

.data-icon {
  color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
  font-size: 45px;
}

.hamburger {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  color: black;
}

.sidenav-closed {
  width: 65px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="sidenav-closed sidenav">
  <button class="hamburger data-disappear">&#9776;</button>
  <div class="icons-only">
    <div class="data-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="data-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="data-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is actually the `.data-icon` that should have `text-align: center;`, but since that property is inherited it still works, and it is not recommended to rely on inheritance as if this change, your solution will stop working. In addition they are floated, which you say nothing about (and the reason they are left aligned)

Comment: `.text-align:center;` on `.data-icon` would work. As for the inheritance _"issue"_, I would say that's subjective and depends on the fluidity of the project/markup going forward. Though not a bad idea. In my example the icons are not floated, removing `text-align: center;` yields the same results as the OP's example.